# how to populate a Dropdown list in the property editor of a custom form element with all the form fields?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I want to create a `custom form element` that has a `property editor` in which user can choose from a `DropDownList` of form fields. Similar to Edit Condition Dialog which user can choose form fields from `DropDownList` but instead of a dialog I want to have this `DropDownList` in the property editor.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the requirement, I checked my solution and find something that might help you. So first of all if we create any custom control then we need to define a Model Type class and then associate it with the custom Sitecore field item in the Model Type field.

That class contains the methods called `InitItemProperties` and `UpdateItemFields` where you can write your logic to bind properties with that control. If you see an example of how an OOTB DropDownList control works, you will get an idea that where you need to write the logic. So when you add DropDownList control and manually add DropDownList items using the property editor then you can see that it fills the "Default chosen list item" drop down in the property editor.

The values yet are not saved in the database but it filled that dropdown. So it is being handled from the javascript function that you can find under this file.

```
wwwroot\<yout-sitecore-instance>\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\FormsBuilder\Layouts\Renderings\KeyValuePairEditor\KeyValuePairEditor.js
```

Also when you open the conditions dialogue, it is also showing you the list of fields that are binding using javascript code that you can find in the below file location.

```
wwwroot\<yout-sitecore-instance>\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\FormsBuilder\Dialogs\EditConditionsDialogWindow\EditConditions.js
```

Here is a code snippet that can help you to understand and write your own logic something like this.

```
show: function(isMultipleFields, items, callbackFn) {
    this.EditConditionsEditor.setFormFields(this.parent.FormDesignBoard.Items,
        this.parent.FormDesignBoard.PageFieldTypes);
    this.EditConditionsEditor.IsMultipleFields = isMultipleFields;
    this.EditConditionsEditor.reset(items);
    this.callbackFn = callbackFn;

    this.EditConditionsDialogWindow.show();
},
```

And finally when you are done with your code, then you need to get those values in your custom field model class like this.

```
protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) item, nameof (item));
      base.UpdateItemFields(item);
     
      string[] array = this.UpdateDataSourceSettings(item).Where<ListFieldItem>((Func<ListFieldItem, bool>) (li => li.Selected && ID.IsID(li.ItemId))).Select<ListFieldItem, string>((Func<ListFieldItem, string>) (li => li.ItemId)).ToArray<string>();
      item.Fields["your field in property editor"]?.SetValue(string.Join("|", array), false);
    }

protected virtual ListFieldItemCollection UpdateDataSourceSettings(
      Item item)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) item, nameof (item));
      ListFieldItemCollection settings = new ListFieldItemCollection();
      settings.AddRange((IEnumerable<ListFieldItem>) this.Items);
      this.DataSourceSettingsManager.SaveSettings(item, settings);
      return settings;
    }
```

This way you can find some help to make this work. But you need to go a bit deeper into the JS logic written to get all the fields on the forms by referring to the javascript files that I mentioned above. But again I will not recommend modifying any existing OOTB logic because I didn't find the code in the backend that can give you the list of the controls on the forms because when you add controls, they exist on the page, not in the database before saving your form.

Hope this will give you an idea.